# Does Cassandra provide read-after-write consistency for a single node?

Tags: database, cassandra, distributed-computing

On a *single node* Cassandra, if I perform

```
write(key=A, value=3)
write(key=A, value=5)
a_value = read(key=A)
```

would `a_value` be 3, or 5? Or in other words, does Cassandra guarantee read-after-write consistency, where we always see the most recent value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, if the sequence of requests of read and write is Write-> Read. If your request is synchronous (session.execute), that means you wait for a response for your write request and after getting successful response you do the read request, then yes you'll get most recent value. Since for a single node, data is not distributed among multiple nodes thus does not have to worry about maintaining consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If you wait for a response, then yes. If you don't wait for a response for the write request then the read request could be handled before.